# How to copy files from Google Chromebook up to Google Drive? in what view or place can I see the two together?

Tags: chromebook, google-drive-for-desktop

Is there a way to sync the Files app folders on Chromebook with Google Drive? If yes, how is that done? Or a way to copy individual files from the Chromebook up to Google Drive?  I don't see my local files when I open Google Drive on the Chromebook.

P.S. I've also found instructions online that say how to change the default location for downloads so it points to Google Drive, but those instructions do not match what I'm seeing. The only option I see is to create a new local folder on the Chromebook so that downloaded files are placed there instead.

Device Info: ACER CP311-2H-C700

O/S: Version 115.0.5790.160 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: Screenshot of Chromebook Files app]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a Chromebook with me right now. Apparently, Google Drive is disabled on your computer as it's not shown in the left panel of the Files App. Are you using a Google Account to sign into your Chromebook, or are you using a local user (not linked to a Google account)? Look at the Files Apps setting and the Chrome settings. Search for an option so link your local account to a Google Account and/or to enable Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

From [Use Google Drive files offline on your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2809731?hl=en)

> You can use Google Drive files offline. This includes Docs, Sheets, Slides, and more.

There are several steps. Below is the section that mentions the Files app.

> #### Use the Files app
>
> 1. At the bottom left, select the Launcher .
> 2. Select Files  and then Google Drive Drive.
> 3. Select the file you want to use offline.
> 4. At the top, turn on Available offline.
>
>    - To show that it’s available offline, a check mark appears next to the file.
>
> Tip: To show all offline files, go to the “Offline” folder in the Files app.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I want to copy files on my Chromebook up to Google Drive. At this point, these files exist only on the Chromebook. When I open the Launcher and select Files as you say to do in step #2, there  is nothing in the Files app that mentions Google Drive, so you've lost me there. I don't see a Google Drive option in the Files app.  That's where I expected to find it, but it's not there.  Is that feature not available on all Chromebooks?

Comment: @TimR Please [edit] the question to add more details like the Chromebook model, the version of the ChromeOS, add screenshots, etc.

Comment: I will try. I'm fairly new to Chromebook and will have to find where to get that info.

Comment: Is what I see on my screen in the Files app different than what you see? Do you have a folder there that points to Google Drive?

Comment: @TimR It looks like Google Drive is disabled on your Chromebook.

Comment: I've found the setting to enable it.  Thank you.

Comment: @TimR Please post the details as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open Chromebook's Settings, then search for "drive" and then go to the Files section and disable "Disconnect Google Drive account", which appears to be toggled to **ON** (i.e. disconnected) by default.